# Pausing Audio in Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to make a digital MPC with buttons that trigger different audio clips.

I got the buttons to function and play the audio when clicked once, however, I'm trying to make the audio pause when clicked again.

I've entered my entire code into this post incase anyone wanted to run it, however my issue is in the Javascript file with the "mousedown" function.

If anyone could offer insight I'd appreciate it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var padOne = new Audio('allstar.mp3');
  $('.pad-1').mousedown(function() {
    padOne.load()
    padOne.play();
    
  });
  
  $(window).keydown(function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode;
    var kc = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    $("div[data-code='"+code+"']").addClass("active")
    console.log(code);
    
    switch(kc) {
      case "R":
        padOne.load();
        padOne.play();
        break;
 
    }
  });

  $(window).keyup(function(e) { 
    var code = e.keyCode;
    $("div[data-code='"+code+"']").removeClass("active");
  });

});
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald';

html, body {
  background: #000000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 5vw;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
}

.pad {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
  background-color: #444;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  user-select: none;
  
  &:hover {
    background-color: lighten(#444, 10%);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  &:active {
    background-color: darken(#444, 10%);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: all .2s;
  }
}

.active {
  background-color: darken(#444, 10%);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all .2s;
}

.pad-1{
  background-image: url(../images/shrek.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Viral Remix</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <h1>VIRAL REMIXER</h1>

<div class="pad">
  <div class="box pad-1" data-code="82">R</div>

</div>




  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script  src="js/scripts.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem you encounter or errors when you run your code? Ll help debug..

Comment: Salus Sage- I dont encounter any errors in the console when I run my code, I'm just not sure what logic or function I need to make the audio pause when the mouse is pressed down for a second time. I can't add "padOne.pause();" in the variable padOne or else it interrupts the call to make it play. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use a boolean flag to represent the playing state.

```
var playing = false;

$('.pad-1').mousedown(function() {
    if(!playing) {
        play();
    } else {
        pause();
    }
});

function play() {
   padOne.load();
   padOne.play();
   playing = true;
}

function pause() {
   padOne.pause();
   playing = false;
}
```